# How to use two network cards, depending on website

Tags: networking, vpn

I have a Windows 7 computer with 2 network cards. I live in China.
I would like to use both of them, one being connected to internet through a VPN (located in the US) #1, the other one directly to internet #2.

What I want to achieve :

- When I connect to the url www.bing.com, I want to access it through network card #2
- But when I connect to the url www.Netflix.com, I want to use the #1 (the one using the VPN)

Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: Here is my verdict: Create a batch file/Visual Basic script to change the network card priority; You would then need to create a listener for network connections and checks the outgoing domain name (it then runs the script to change the network card). Just my verdict...

Comment: But I want to be able to use Netflix through the VPN, and at the same time using www.youku.com (the chinese youtube) through normal internet. Would that be possible with your solution ?

Comment: I'm off to do research so I actually have a *solution*...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.cmds/doc/aixcmds4/route.htm you might be able to put in a custom route for specific sites, till it's all figured out.  if you fiddle the route table for netflix, all the other sites would use card#2, good luck figuring it out, but, it looks like it'd do the job.

Comment: This is for AIX tho, He's running windows.

Comment: Check out the 'route' command in Windows... `route /?` will give you subcommands.

Comment: yes, most of the tools that exist on multiple os's, they use the same commands.  network stuff is multiplatorm, like route, bind, ping, HOSTS, usually the same commands and file formats.